# Securing apple remote desktop to brute force attacks on a public LAN

Tags: network, remote-desktop

A client of ours uses Apple remote desktop for IT support in the office. To access a computer remote management needs to be enabled via System Preferences > Sharing and the user who is requesting remote access needs the username / password for the user currently using the computer they are logging into.

The concern is for laptop users in a coffee shop / airport etc. As they will be on the same LAN as many other people, anyone using Apple Remote Desktop could try and log into their computer.

The username / password is stopping them, but the username is often quite easy to guess as most peoples computer name is also their username. Eg. if i scanned the LAN in apple remote desktop and saw a computer called "Sam's Laptop" good chance that user's username is "Sam".

Passwords for web services, email passwords, VPNs etc are a random generated 40-60 character string. But for computer login password most people use simple passwords, which are easier to break through brute force.

Is there a way as an extra security layer we can set incoming Apple Remote Desktop connections to only allow connections from pre approved computers. Or put a wrong password / username time out ?

Comment: Presumably the IT support comes from the same IP each time? Why not create a firewall rule only allowing traffic to TCP 5900 from IT's office?